# QML ListModel: are multiple ListModels allowed to live on screen?

Tags: qt, gridview

```
GridView {
 id: gridv
 model: ListModel {
  id: modelone;
 }
 delegate: componentId
}
Rectangle {
 id: whattheproblem
 color: red
 ListView {
  id: listv
  model: ListModel {
   id: modeltwo;
  }
  delegate: anotherComponentId
 }
}
```

I can do `gridv.model.append(element)`, it adds elements to displayed GridView.
But, I can't do `listv.model.append(element)`, it doesn't draw anything (the component code is valid, though), but at the same time, `modeltwo.count` shows that element is added to model. `Rectangle` was added to check the layout (it's managed by RowLayout currently), and it seems to be working; other layout things (think `anchor`, `x/y/z`) do not help.

QT 5.3, QtQuick 2..

*From my point of view, I can only think now, that `modelone` associates all the ListModel logics to GridView it's created from, so ListModel can't work with ListView anymore. Sounds illogical, but already spent two hours on this.*

is there a necessity to create custom Model's, when dealing with multiple views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the delegate, since i tried your example with some modifications and it worked.
Following is the code:

```
Item {
width: 200
height: 200
GridView {
    id: gridv
    width: 200
    height: 100
    model: ListModel {
        id: modelone;
    }
    delegate: Text { text: name }
}
Rectangle {
    id: whattheproblem
    anchors.top: gridv.bottom
    ListView {
        id: listv
        model: ListModel {
            id: modeltwo;
        }
        delegate: Text { text: name }
    }
}

Button {
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    text: "Add to Grid"
    onClicked: gridv.model.append({name: "grid"})
}
Button {
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    text: "Add to List"
    onClicked: listv.model.append({name: "list"})
}
```

}

I tried it with Qt 5.3.1